# How to fix : Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null error in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a custom calendar in my app. While developing code in *JavaScript* it worked. After when I tried to migrate my code to Angular 6 it is not working properly. Angular throwing a run-time error. Which I'm not able to resolve,

Anyone please help me with this!

This is the Stack-Blitz link which I'm working on :[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3u4g4)!

```
showCalendar(month, year) {
const firstDay = (new Date(year, month)).getDay();
const daysInMonth = 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate();

console.log('\n val \n' + new Date(year, month, 32).getDate());

const tbl = document.getElementById('calendar-body');

// clearing all previous cells
tbl.innerHTML = '';

// filing data about month and in the page via DOM.
this.monthAndYear.innerHTML = this.months[month] + ' ' + year;

 // creating all cells
let date = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement('tr');

    for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        // let cell = document.createElement('td');
        if (i === 0 && j < firstDay) {
            const cell = document.createElement('td');
            const cellText = document.createTextNode('');
            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        } else if (date > daysInMonth) {
            break;
        } else {
            const cell = document.createElement('td');
            const cellText = document.createTextNode(date.toString());
        if (date === this.today.getDate() && year === this.today.getFullYear() && month === this.today.getMonth()) {
            // cell.classList.add("bg-info");
        } // color todays date
            date++;
        }
    }
    tbl.appendChild(row); // appending each row into calendar body.
  }
}

constructor() {
 this.today = new Date();
 this.currentMonth = this.today.getMonth();
 this.currentYear = this.today.getFullYear();
 this.monthAndYear = document.getElementById('monthAndYear');
}

ngOnInit() {
 this.showCalendar(this.currentMonth, this.currentYear);
 console.log('ngOnInit');
}
```

Expected result is It show a calendar.

But it is giving the error as:
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at CustomCalendarComponent.push../src/app/components/custom-calendar/custom-calendar.component.ts.CustomCalendarComponent.showCalendar (custom-calendar.component.ts:67)`

Comment: Please, please, please, please, please stop direct accessing the DOM in Angular. That's not an Angular way to achieve a result, that's just a way to execute normal code in a heavier way

Comment: this.monthAndYear is null  - thats what stackblitz says so you got different problem here.

Comment: @Antoniossss When I open the log innerHtml error which I'm seeing.

Comment: Nope, no error.

Answer (score 1):

Move `document.getElementByid('monthAndYear')` to ngOnInit since there is no attached DOM yet when contructor is called.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzzvsb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Besides that, the entire calendar generation logic is broken so you will have to work on it. Rows and cells are added. However, why you set them as empty is a mystery.

Comment: apologize, while copying code from local machine to stackblitz I missed some lines of code. Now I updated my code in Stack-Blitz.

Answer (score 1):

Angular use separate API for manipulate DOM.The Renderer2 provided by Angular in the form of a service that allows to manipulate elements of your app without having to touch the DOM direct

If you want to Select specific element from DOM use template variable, then use  ViewChild decorator to access the element inside component class

**component.html**

```
<h3 class="card-reader" id="monthAndYear" #monthAndYear> Month and Year</h3>
```

**component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('monthAndYear') monthAndYear: ElementRef;
```

Create  New element Use Renderer2

```
      constructor(private ren: Renderer2) {}
      const cell = this.ren.createElement('td');
      const cellText = this.ren.createText('');
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
```

Ref:https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/

Forked Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-up1ibg